# Trying to delete specific checked elements using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I can't seem to figure out how to delete an element using jQuery. I'm creating a sample shopping list app and I'm able to add items as needed but I cannot figure out how to remove checked items. What am I missing?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('.addStuff').on('click', function() {
var htmlStr = '<div class = "appItem"> <div class = "priority"> Priority: <select> <option value="high"> High</option> <option value="medium"> Medium</option> <option value="low"> Low </option> </select> </div> Done: <input type = "checkbox" class = "checkDone" name = "status" value = "done" /> <br/> To do item: <input type ="text" class = "listItem"  name = "item" /> </div>';
$(this).closest('#outsideBox').append(htmlStr);
});

$('.removeStuff').on('click',function(){

 var checkedstuff = $(this).closest('#outsideBox').find('.checkDone').is(':checked');
 checkedstuff.hide();

});
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<html >
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> ShopIt </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "shoppapp.css" />
        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="shopapp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>

    <h1> Shop It! </h1>
    <div id = "outsideBox">
        <div id = "functionButtons">
        <button class = "addStuff"> Add Item </button>
        <button class = "removeStuff"> Remove Checked Items </button>
        </div>
        <div class = "appItem">
            <div class = "priority">
            Priority: <select> 
                <option value="high"> High</option>
                <option value="medium"> Medium</option>
                <option value="low"> Low </option>
            </select>
            </div>

            Done: <input type = "checkbox" class = "checkDone" name = "status" value = "done" /><br/>
            To do item: <input type ="text" class = "listItem"  name = "item" />
        </div>
    </div>
<footer>
    <p> Thinful Project, Unit 3 </p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var checkedstuff = $(this).closest('#outsideBox').find('.checkDone').is(':checked');`
will return a `bool` since `.is()` returns either true or false

Comment: Changing `is` to `filter`, and targeting the right element, here's something "working": http://jsfiddle.net/hsPgs/ . Note that `$(this).closest('#outsideBox')` is unnecessary (and causes jQuery to do much more work than necessary) - you can just use `$("#outsideBox")` because `id` attributes should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is() returns a boolean. You can use the :checked selector. Then use parent() to remove the entire parent of the shopping item. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MKPcK/

```
var checkedstuff = $(this).closest('#outsideBox').find('.checkDone:checked').parent();
 checkedstuff.hide();
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. I figured it had to be something simple I was missing. Thanks!

Comment: Just keep in mind that hide() will only set a "display: none" on the element, hiding it, but it still occupies memory, it'll still be present in DOM, so if you want them to be deleted (freeing memory space also), use remove() instead.

Comment: Good point Nicolae. Use hide() only if you want to show() it afterwards or otherwise use the hidden data.

Comment: And I'll also recommend using [...].find('.checkDone:checked').closest('.appItem') to get the parent div, because if you're gonna change your 'htmlStr' inside your addStuff click handler, and your checkboxes will be nested at least 1 level deeper, [...].find('.checkDone:checked').parent() won't work as expected. But... as long as you keep your 'checkDone' checkboxes as direct children of 'appItem', the code will work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.removeStuff').on('click', function() {
    $('#outsideBox').find('.checkDone:checked').closest('.appItem').remove();
});
```